# Unable to Navigate to diffrent tabs in BottomBar

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, bottombar

I am using the Roughike bottombar and trying with xml >> tabs. I am unable to navigate to different tabs in the bottom bar, I click on the particular icon and nothing comes up. Please check and advise. Also do let me know if you need any further information.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.vt.HomeFragment;

import com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar;
import com.roughike.bottombar.OnTabSelectListener;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BottomBar bottomBar = (BottomBar) findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);
        bottomBar.setOnTabSelectListener(new OnTabSelectListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(@IdRes int tabId) {
                    if (tabId == R.id.tab_home){
                        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeFragment.class);
                        startActivity(homeIntent);
                    } else if (tabId == R.id.tab_gallery){
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Gallery",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (tabId == R.id.tab_profile){
                        Intent profileIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyProfile.class);
                        startActivity(profileIntent);
                    } else if(tabId == R.id.tab_location){
                        Intent locationIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LocationFragment.class);
                        startActivity(locationIntent);

                    }

            }
        });



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Roughike bottombar is deprecated. It is recommended to use BottomNavigationView.

Comment: Thanks, Will do that.!